# Difference between ViewParent and ViewGroup?

Tags: android, xml

[ViewParent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html)

> Defines the responsibilities for a class that will be a parent of a
>   View. This is the API that a view sees when it wants to interact with
>   its parent.

[ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup)

> A ViewGroup is a special view that can contain other views (called
>   children.) The view group is the base class for layouts and views
>   containers.

I'm struggling to differentiate the two - they're both parents of a set of views. What does `ViewParent` do that `ViewGroup` can't (why can't ViewParent's functionality just be added to ViewGroup)?

Comment: `ViewParent` is an `interface`. `ViewGroup` is an `abstract class` that implements `ViewParent`. As far as I know, the only thing that implements `ViewParent` that's not a `ViewGroup` is `ViewRootImpl`, which is the very top of a `View` hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in documentation, `ViewParent` is an interface.

A child view can access its parent via `getParent()` ([doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getParent())) which returns a `ViewParent`.

This parent may be a `ViewGroup` as it implements the interface but you can't know that from the child object without a "instanceof" check.

There could be a class implementing ViewParent and not being a ViewGroup... (I didn't find it though)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are 2 implementations of `ViewParent`:

1. [`ViewGroup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup)

   > A `ViewGroup` is a special view that can contain other views (called children.) The view group is the base class for layouts and views containers.

   - implementations include things like `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, `FrameLayout`
2. [`ViewRootImpl`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/ViewRootImpl.java)

   > The top of a view hierarchy, implementing the needed protocol between View
   > and the WindowManager.  This is for the most part an internal implementation
   > detail of {@link WindowManagerGlobal}.

   - as far as I know, usually each app is placed into its own [`Window`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window) which is then shown on the screen. Android can then show multiple windows from different apps simultaneously in [multi-window mode (AKA split-screen mode)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/multi-window-support), or [picture-in-picture mode](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/picture-in-picture)

Answer (score 0):

**View**
    1. View objects are the basic building blocks of User Interface(UI) elements in Android.
    2.View is a simple rectangle box which responds to the user's actions.
    3. Examples are EditText, Button, CheckBox etc..
    4. View refers to the android.view.View class, which is the base class of all UI classes.

**ViewGroup**
1. ViewGroup is the invisible container. It holds View and ViewGroup.
2. For example, LinearLayout is the ViewGroup that contains Button(View), and other Layouts also.
3. ViewGroup is the base class for Layouts.